# How can I remove a site from a Chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome

If there are a lot of sites on a Chrome tab, a site on the tab that is compute or graphics intensive - say a page with panning and zooming animation - will stutter. So how can I remove sites from a tab so that only the intensive site is left?

Comment: usually clicking the X in the corner of the tab works for me. This closes the tab window. Also try CTRL+F4 keys as well.

Comment: Uh, are you looking for code to accomplish this?  If not this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Marin, CTRL+F4 closes the tab.  I just want to close the site, so the tab has one less site on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking the "x" on the tab to get rid of it. If it's really stuttering, which I've seen happen on a number of occasions, try Ctrl+W to close the tab. If it gets particularly bad, Alt+F4 will close Chrome. You can then reopen Chrome and manually reopen whichever tabs you just lost that you want to see.

Comment: This is how I could delete the tab but that's not what I want to do.  I'm beginning to think there's no way to just pull off one site and maybe the reason is that deleting one site from history would break history.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull off of one site"? What exactly are you trying to do? Removing sites from Chrome's history won't "break" the history.